# An activity control flow if a new activity is started

Tags: android, android-activity

So suppose there is ActivityA:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if (AndroidUtils.isDeviceRooted()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
     }

     ....
     // other code of onCreate()
}
```

I am aware of the fact that `startActivity()` is async and the current activity finishes after the new is started. If this is the case then some portion of the "other code of onCreate()" will be executed, right?

**EDIT**: following the answer is there a way to NOT execute the code after `startActivity()` in `onCreate()`? Like calling `finish()` or `return` or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely Right. But not the some but all code of your onCreate will be called.

Following will be the flow of your both Activity

When ever you navigate from ActivityA to ActivityB then onPause() of ActivityA method is called followed by the onStop() of ActivityA and then the method onCreate() of ActivityB is called followed by onStart() of ActivityB and then onResume() of ActivityB.

Also when navigating back to of ActivityA by pressing back key

onPause() of ActivityB is called followed by the onStop() of ActivityB and then the method onRestart() of ActivityA of first activity is called followed by onStart() of ActivityA and then onResume() of ActivityA.

But as you are navigated from ActivityA before onResume called so onPause will not be called for ActivityB.

Answer (score 1):

> following the answer is there a way to NOT execute the code after
>   startActivity() in onCreate()? Like calling finish() or return or
>   both.

if you call `finish()` once activity is created the `ondestroy` will be called immediately 
and `onpause` and `onStop` etc will be skipped

```
boolean isRooted;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 isRooted=AndroidUtils.isDeviceRooted();

 if (isRooted) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
 }else{
     ....
     // other code of onCreate()
 }

}
```